# Mule: Using POJOs on a LinkedList variable

Tags: java, json, mule, mule-studio

I've a flow that performs a "for each" loop, extracts the current loop data and pases it to a Connector. The connector returns a different class of POJO.

Now, I set put a variable of the type LinkedList, and enrich said variable with each loop on the foreach. As I understand, now my LinkedList has an element with each of the different POJOs my connector passed.

My question is, when the for-each process ends, and my variable is enriched, how can I extract the values from it. Or my approach is incorrect? If I just print to the client (REST client) the results, it shows that it is a LinkedList... but don't don't know what to do from there. I'm thinking if there is a way to transform that to a JSON, or what approach is the best for my case.

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of trial and error I found a way, but I don't know if it is the proper one:

```
#[mylinkedlist[mylinkedlist.size()-1].getXXXXX()]
```

That actually brings the info, obviously I can set the number of the element of the list, and it works fine. Is this the right approach, or there's something better (cleaner, efficient, standard, good looking)?

Thanks!